# How to pass a vendor-specific options to a DHCP server using dhclient?

Tags: linux, configuration, client, dhcp

I am trying to configure dhclient. The specification says that I should add vendor-specific options in every DHCP request/solicitation.

I've found only -V option.

-V 
    Specify the vendor-class-identifier option to send to the DHCP server.

I am not sure that is what I need.

I saw that some options can be setted in dhclient.cfg, but honestly I didn't get at all how I can do this. :(
As I understand there is some "language" but I can't find helpful description or examples.

Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's documented reasonably well in the [dhcp-options man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcp-options).

For example:

```
option space ISC code width 1 length width 1 hash size 3;
option ISC.sample code 1 = text;
option vendor.ISC code 2495 = encapsulate vivso-sample;
option vendor-class.ISC code 2495 = text;

option ISC.sample "configuration text here";
option vendor-class.ISC "vendor class here";
```

Comment: Do you cnow how to send vendor class id? I do thiS: send vendor-class-identifier "OpenCable2.1"; but DHCP server doesn't receive that value.

Comment: Have you used wireshark to check what is really being sent?

Comment: I used tcpdump to collect all data and after that used wireshark.